# Jquery traversing table elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using Jquery to dynamically populate the table element. My table will have three columns - Label, textarea and a button. I am binding a click event on click of the button. Below is my Jquery code.

```
var rowElem = $('<tr id="'+ key + '" class="queryRow"> </tr>');
rowElem.append($('<td class="queryTitleCol">' + key + '</td>')); 
var colElem = $('<td class="queryValueCol"></td>');
var textAreaElem = $('<textarea rows="10" cols="75"/>');
colElem.append(textAreaElem);
rowElem.append(colElem);
textAreaElem.val(value);
var btnCol = $(
            '<td valign="top">'
            + '<button style="width:42px; vertical-align:middle; margin:2px;" title="delete">'
            +   '<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash" style="float:left;"/>'
            + '</button>'
            +'</td>');
    rowElem.append(btnCol);
    $("button", btnCol).click(action);
}
```

In the button event I am using Jqury.closest to get the TR tag and label element. Below is my code for button click.

```
function action() { 
var rowElem = $(this).closest("tr");
var labelTD = $(".queryTitleCol", rowElem);
}
```

But labelTD , I am always getting as [td.queryTitleCol] as an array. I am not able to get the td element to get the lable element. I tried with find(), but still I am getting as td array.

```
rowElem.find('td.queryTitleCol');
```

How can I traverse and get the label name on click function of the button. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var label = $(".queryTitleCol", rowElem)[0].innerHTML;
```

or

```
var label = $(".queryTitleCol", rowElem).text();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
$('button').click(function(){
  $(this).prev('.queryTitleCol').text();
});
```

This will always grab the previous element with `queryTitleCol` as its class. It only returns one element, so you shouldn't run into the problem you've been describing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function action() { 
     var titleCol = $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(0)').text();
}
```

Check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/n7aSb/)